# how to group JSON objects by nested keys in python

Tags: python, json, nested

I have passed a CSV file to JSON. I have something like this:

```
[{
      "Intent": "About",
      "Texto": "quien"
   },
 {
      "Intent": "NP_Contacto",
      "Texto": "atencion"
   },
   {
      "Intent": "NP_Contacto",
      "Texto": "informacion?"
   },
   {
      "Intent": "NP_Contacto",
      "Texto": "hablar"
   },
   {
      "Intent": "NP_Contacto",
      "Texto": "numero"
   }]
```

but I want this:

```
[{             "intent": "NP_Contacto",
                "texto": [{
                        "text": "telefono"
                    },
                    {
                        "text": "hablar"
                    },
                    {
                        "text": "número"
                    },
                    {
                        "text": "atención"
                    },
                    {
                        "text": "informacion"
                    }
                ]
            },
{
      "Intent": "About",
      "Texto": "quien"
   },

]
```

The code I have used to create this is:

```
reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, fieldnames=("Texto", "Intent")) 
fieldnames = ("Texto", "Intent") 

output = [] 

for each in reader: 
    row = {} for field in fieldnames: 
    row[field] = each[field] 
    output.append(row) 

json.dump(output, jsonfile, indent=3, sort_keys=True)
```

Comment: Please show us the code you have already tried.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are just trying to regroup it.
So try something like:

```
for i in json:
    for j,k in i.items():
        ...
```